# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - Parsing JSON data in $.ajax()

Tags: php, ajax, json, parsing

I have a question relates to parsing the data that comes from PHP handler and display it. To perform this action I'm using `$.ajax()` function and sending string to the server with the request. The PHP handler returns desired data as `echo json_encode($result);` and also prints fine in console. But while the parsing I meet with the folowing problem: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token**

[image]

**JS handler:**

```
function displayFields(cid, qid) {

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getQuizzes.php',
    //  dataType: 'json',
        data: {courseid:cid, questionid:qid},
        success: function(data) {
            // display json response from php
            console.log(data);
            // dislpaying data in html
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            var html = '';
            $.each(json, function(index, item) {
                html += '<div id="' + item.id + '"><h3>' + item.question + '</h3></div>';
            });
            $('#questionList').html(html);
        },
        error: function(XMLhttprequest, textstatus, errorthrown) {
            console.log("error: " + textstatus + "(" + errorthrown + ")");
        }
    });

}
```

I tried to look at similar problems existing in stack-overflow, but couldn't find the solution relating to syntax error in ajax use. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

**PHP Handler:**

```
$select = "SELECT `qid`, `question` FROM `test` WHERE course_id='".$_POST['courseid']."'";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die ("<b>Select to DB failed:</b> " . mysqli_error());
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$result = array();

if ($numrows > 0) {
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $result[] = array('id' => $rows['qid'], 'question' => $rows['question']);
    }
} else {
    $result[] = 'No data yet';
}
echo json_encode($result);

// free the results
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Comment: Screenshots are an absolutely terrible way to describe a coding problem. The text can't be indexed or analysed properly in any way

Comment: @Phil, the reason to put screenshot was to justify the JSON response from PHP handler.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. If you have a JSON parse error, it would make sense to post the **actual JSON**

Comment: @Phil, Please have a look into **UPDATE** part of my question. This is the procedure which returns me json data

Comment: In my opinion, the free'ing of the result should come before the `echo` statement, as in this case, you are essentially using this script as an ENDPOINT and therefore nothing should execute after the return of the data. Furthermore, please check for extenuating `white space` which may be interpreted and passed to the browser. please add `exit()` after the `echo` to see if that resolves your issue, and if so, you've identified the problem at hand.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I have made changes according to your suggestions, the result is still the same.

Comment: While you're making PHP changes, consider using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of injecting the `courseid` value directly into the query. Also, what connection encoding are you using (see http://php.net/manual/mysqli.set-charset.php)?

Comment: What is the character encoding of the database and of the script and of the browser page.

Comment: @Phil I'm using `mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SET CHARSET UTF8');` in my DB connection configuration and all my files are saved in UTF8.

Comment: @Dozent Obviously you didn't read the part on [this page](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.set-charset.php#refsect1-mysqli.set-charset-notes) where that is **not** recommended

Comment: What is the content encoding header of the response? You should be able to see it in your browser's *Net* console tab.

Comment: @Phil, Ok I changed character encoding line with `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")` line.

Comment: @Phil The header of the response is `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`

Comment: @Dozent Why not `application/json`? Seems more appropriate. Also, I asked you what the **actual response header** was, not what you were setting it to in PHP

Comment: @Phil In case of `application/json` in php handler nothing happens (i.e. bo json data in console) and the actual response header it is `content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure your json is well formatted just add :

```
ob_clean();
```

before `echo(...)` instruction

Comment: There is something in the buffer that was previously written by the code. Using ob_clean() will clean it and only the data that you want will be displayed.